# Connecting to VS2010 Remote Debugger from a domain?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dns, remote-debugging, workgroup

I'm trying to set up a remote debugger connection from my dev box on a domain to a web server (SERVER) in a workgroup with no success and I'm hoping for the some insight.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor 
named 'SERVER'.  The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor 
(MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. Please see 
Help for assistance.
```

At this point, I have done the following:

1. I've installed the x64 debugging components, but not as a service. The monitor is up and running.
2. I've created an account on the workgroup machine to match my domain account in name and password.
3. I've granted this account the "Debug programs" right in Local Security Policy.
4. I've added this account the "Administrators" group.

Still I get the same error message.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to create a local account on your dev box with the same name and password as your domain account.

This account just needs to exist - you don't need to run VS with it.